# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method - Conflict during migration: Google Places SDK and Volley

Tags: android, google-places

While migrating to the new [Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_client_library), I faced this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;J)V in class Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/DiskBasedCache$CountingInputStream; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CountingInputStream' appears in /data/app/com.xx.xxx-SfwuN0IipN88dVqeHkiSvQ==/base.apk)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:166)
    at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
```

I'm using volley (which is imported as a project) in my app. I figure the crash is occurring due to a version conflict?

Comment: Oops. Thanks, @Henry, edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to exclude volley from the places library to make it work.

**Before**:

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
}
```

**After**:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0' ){
    exclude module: 'volley'
}
```